# Svelte event with Typescript has type`never`

Tags: typescript, svelte

I have a component like:

```js
<script lang="ts">
    function onCloseModal({ redirect }: any) {
        goto(redirect || "/")
    }
</script>

<Modal on:close={onCloseModal} />
```

Inside `Modal.svelte` I do this:

```js
    function close() {
        setTimeout(() => dispatch("close", { redirect }), duration)
    }
```

Now, I'm getting this error at `on:close={onCloseModal}` from the compiler although the build works -_-

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(event: never, handler: (e: never) => any): void', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '"close"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(event: never, handler: (e: CustomEvent<any>) => any): void', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '"close"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.ts(2769)
```

Why is TS inferring `never` for the event although I'm dispatching the string+payload? How can I let it understand the actual event?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a *non-ts* REPL? BTW, the custom events launched from the event dispatcher are typed as `CustomEvent<any>` where the generic indicates the type of the payload. I just tried your example and it worked: `function onCloseModal(e: CustomEvent<{redirect: string}>) { ... }`.

Comment: Thank you @CarlosRoso for the hint on the types! It makes the editor happier although I still get the error message.

Can you please elaborate more on "non-ts REPL" ? I'd be happy to give you more information. Thanks!

Comment: Does this issue still persist? Is it about the VSCode extension or about the `svelte-check` cli tool? If it's the latter, try updating to the latest version.